# Is it possible inheritance here?Does Inner parent class extends outer child class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, inner-classes

```
A
|_A1
|  |_parent.java
|_child.java
```

does parent.java inherits child.java in any possible way?

here A and A1 are packages or directories

Comment: What are A, A1? Folders? Classes? We have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I have seen a series of poor questions from you over the last one week, are you asking questions for fun - or are you really trying to learn something. If you intend to continue on this site, please accept answers (see the link org.life has posted) else no one will respond to your questions any more.

Answer (score 1):

Only if Child has an `extends` clause

```
public class Child extends Parent{}
```

If so, `Child` will have access to all `public` and `protected` members of `Parent`. Otherwise, `Child` will only have access to `public` members of `Parent`.

If files are inside the same directory hierarchy, but not within the same directory, the packages are not considered related, and hence members with default ("package-protected") visibility are not visible.

**Relevant reading:**

- [Java Tutorial: Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
- [Java Tutorial: Inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: The question is "does _parent_ extens _child_", so the answer should be "only if _parent_ has an extends clause". Not that it makes much sense, though.

Comment: True, but I thought that was a mistake, so I wrote it in the more sensible way

Answer (score 1):

Your picture shows folders and java source files. We have one folder `A` that contains the file `child.java` and another folder `A1`. `A1` contains the java source file `parent.java`.

Arranging source files (or class file) in filesystem  folers does not create or declare relationships between classes.

If you want class `parent` to inherit (from) class `child` (iaw: `parent` inherits fields and method from `child` - strange in real world but possible), you have to declare this relation in the java source code. Keeping your names, the files have to look like this:

**child.java**

```
package A;
public class child {};
```

**parent.java**

```
package A.A1;
import A.child;
public class child extends parent {};
```

**Note** - java naming conventions strongly recommend, that package names are all lower case and class names start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

What I understood is that it is your package/tree hierarchy and you asked for any inheritance.
If there is any inheritance, does it look like any inheritance/tree hierarchy? If you destroy the inheritance tree it means there **shouldn't** be any inherited class under any other irrelevant package or under any other node. In other words, lack of design pattern. If you do this, you will handle the redundant accesibility in package-level and with other packages and so you can't talk anything about OO or any encapsulation in this project